# Is there a way to validate hidden field values?

Tags: vb.net, hidden-field

I am trying to create an if statement that compares the hidden field value. This is a datetime, and if the value is either "" or " - " then I want it to route to the else statement, but this isn't working.

If statement:

```
If hfTo.Value IsNot "" AndAlso hfTo.Value IsNot "-" Then
    dvLossData.RowFilter = "StartTime >= '" + hfFrom.Value + "' and EndTime <= '" + hfTo.Value + "'"
Else
    dvLossData.RowFilter = "StartTime >= '" + hfFrom.Value + "'"
End If
```

`hfto.value` should be "" or "-" when the datetime is in the future. If I debug, I notice that `hfto.value` is " - ", so I added that in the if statement, but it doesn't recognize it.

Does anyone have insight?

Comment: Has the value spaces before and after the - char?

Comment: You should use `<>` instead of `IsNot`. Also, the string concatenation operator in VB is `&`, not `+`.

Answer (score -1):

AndAlso will only evaluate the second portion of the comparison (hfTo.Value IsNot "-") if the first part is True.  Since the field cannot be both "" and "-", the entire statement will never evaluate to TRUE.  Try using And instead of AndAlso.

Comment: This is wrong. Imagine `hfTo.Value` is actually a string `Yes`. `Yes` is NOT `""` and also NOT `"-"`